# jquery navigate in code

Tags: jquery

Hi trying to fade out elements on the page when a navigation link is clicked, then go to the clicked link:

```
$("#navigation a").click(function() {   
  var $clickobj = $this;  
  $("div#content").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 'slow',function(){  
        $("div#navigation").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 'slow', function(){  
          $("div#logo").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 900, function(){  
     $clickobj.click();       
     });  
      });  
   });  
   return false;  
 });
```

but this just navigates straight away with the fade out...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably doing this because `$this` on your first line throws an undefined error and so ti'ts not executing the script, just erroring then continuing the normal anchor behavior.  The `$this` should just be `this` without the `$`, like this:

```
$("#navigation a").click(function() {   
  var $clickobj = $(this).unbind('click');
  $("div#content").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 'slow',function(){  
    $("div#navigation").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 'slow', function(){  
      $("div#logo").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 900, function(){  
        $clickobj.click();       
      });  
    });  
  });  
  return false;  
});
```

Also the `.unbind()` above removes this handler, so it won't loop.

Comment: It should be `$(this)` (he calls `.click()` on it later...)

Comment: @Felix - There's a native DOM click that works for this as well, it's an anchor.  In this case though, he needs to unbind the click handler so it won't loop, so the jQuery version works too.

Comment: Oh... didn't know that... (damn). OK, I will never try to correct you again ;)

Comment: @Felix - I mess up at least 100x a day (who doesn't?), *please* **do** correct, helps the next person that finds this :)

Comment: @Felix - You're right! I happened to be testing something in IE when firing jsfiddle up for this, anchor `.click()` [is IE specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536363.aspx) (big surprise?)

Answer (score 0):

The animation runs on a timer so you need to wait for that to finish. This code looks like it is going into a recursive loop, so rather call window.location once the third animation is finished:

```
$("#navigation a").click(function(e) {   
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $("div#content").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 'slow',function(){  
        $("div#navigation").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 'slow', function(){  
          $("div#logo").animate({opacity: 'toggle', paddingTop: '0px'}, 900, function(){  
     window.location = href;       
     });  
      });  
   });  
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```